# Optimising a working MYSQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**Background**

I have a table of "users", a table of "content", and a table of "content_likes". When a user "likes" an item of content, a relation is added to "content_likes". Simple.

Now what I am trying to do is order content based on the number of likes it has received. This is relatively easy, however, I only want to retrieve 10 items at a time and then with a lazy load I am retrieving the next 10 items and so forth. If the select was ordered by time it would be easy to do the offset in the select statement, however, due to the ordering by number of "likes" I need another column I can offset by. So I've added a "rank" column to the result set, then on the next call of 10 items I can offset by this.

This query WORKS and does what I need to do. However, I am concerned about performance. Could anyone advise on optimising this query. Or even possibly a better way of doing it.

**DB SCHEMA**

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `content` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`owner_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`added` int(11) NOT NULL,
`deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `content_likes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`content_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`added` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

*columns omitted for simplicity

**Breakdown of query**

- group content_id in content_likes relations table, and order by likes desc
- add a column "rank" (or row number) to result set and order by this
- join "content" table so that any content with a deleted flag can be ommited
- only return results where "rank" (or row number) is greater than variable
- limit result set to 10

**THE MYSQL**

```
SELECT 
    results.content_id, results.likes, results.rank
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            t1.content_id, t1.likes, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                cl.content_id, 
                COUNT(cl.content_id) AS likes
            FROM
                content_likes cl
            GROUP BY
                cl.content_id
            ORDER BY
                likes DESC,
                added DESC
        ) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
        ORDER BY
            rank ASC
    ) results
LEFT JOIN
    content c
ON
    (c.id = results.content_id)
WHERE
    c.deleted <> 1
AND
    results.rank > :lastRank
LIMIT
    10
```

**MYSQL ALTERNATIVE**

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        results.*, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            c.id, cl.likes 
        FROM 
            content c
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT content_id, COUNT(content_id) AS likes FROM content_likes GROUP BY content_id ORDER BY likes DESC, added DESC) cl
        ON
            c.id = cl.content_id
        WHERE 
            c.deleted <> 1 
        AND 
            c.added > :timeago 
        LIMIT
            100
    ) results, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
) final
WHERE
    final.rank > :lastRank
LIMIT
    5
```

The "Alternative" mysql query works as I would like it too also. Content is ordered by number of likes by users and I can offset by inserting the last row number. What I have attempted to do here is limit the result sets so if and when the tables get large performance isn't hindered too badly. In this example only content from within a timespan, and limit to 100 will be returned. Then I can offset by the row number (lazy load/pagination)

Any help or advice always appreciated. I am relatively a newbie to mysql so be kind :)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the definition of your tables, including indexes.

Comment: No - please show the full structure, including the engine, index definitions, and cardinality. And an explain plan for that query (although there's jhuge scope for tuning it even without seeing the details).

Comment: Hi symcbean, I've made an edit and I hope it is what you are seeking. Apologies for the newbie annoyances.

Answer (score 2):

You can eliminate the subquery:

```
SELECT results.content_id, results.likes, results.rank
FROM (SELECT cl.content_id, COUNT(cl.content_id) AS likes, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank
      FROMc content_likes cl cross join
            (SELECT @rn:=0) t2
      GROUP BY cl.content_id
      ORDER BY likes DESC, added DESC
     ) results LEFT JOIN
    content c
    ON c.id = results.content_id
WHERE c.deleted <> 1 AND
      results.rank > :lastRank
LIMIT 10;
```

However, I don't think that will have an appreciable affect on performance.  What you should probably do is store the last number number of likes and "added" value and use these to filter the data.  The query needs to be a little fixed up, because `added` is not unambiguously defined in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT results.content_id, results.likes, results.rank, results.added
FROM (SELECT cl.content_id, COUNT(cl.content_id) AS likes, MAX(added) as added, @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank
      FROMc content_likes cl cross join
            (SELECT @rn := :lastRank) t2
      WHERE likes < :likes or
            likes = :likes and added < :added
      GROUP BY cl.content_id
      ORDER BY likes DESC, added DESC
     ) results LEFT JOIN
    content c
    ON c.id = results.content_id
WHERE c.deleted <> 1 AND
      results.rank > :lastRank
LIMIT 10;
```

This will at least reduce the number of rows that need to be sorted.

Comment: Hey Gordon, Ive added a mysql alternative query to my question. What do you think?

Comment: @MartinCurrah . . . Your alternative looks fine, although it still has an additional subquery that is not necessary.  For 100 records, this probably isn't a big overhead in terms of performance.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, Gordon. The reason I have the additional subquery is so that the rank stays in order. Otherwise it gets mixed up with the sorting by likes. The rank needs to be in order for the offset to be affective. Appreciate your expertise.

Comment: You can do that sort in the outer query.